# Does size() on std::list work by traversing the list from beginning to end and counting the number of elements?

Tags: c++

I was going through a tutorial on Containers from the C++ standard library and was taken aback when the instructor told that the size of the `std::list` isn't stored as part of the list, instead it is found by traversing through the list end to end and returning the count unlike with `std::vector`.

Is this true?! If yes, why don't they just store the size as part of the class and update the size every time a node is added or removed from the list? What am I missing here?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: From C++11 onward `size()` is required to be an `O(1)` operation, so it must be a cached value.

Comment: *the instructor told that the size of the std::list isn't stored as part of the list, instead it is found by traversing through the list end to end and returning the count* -- The instructor is wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah dang! I knew something was amiss.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it depends on how old the info of the instructors' is. GCC before version 5 had an `O(N)` `std::list::size()`

Comment: @NathanOliver By cached value, do you mean it is stored as the data member of the std::list class?

Comment: @ZoomIn Yes.  It is now required to keep a size variable in the class with the current size.

Comment: That's why a C++11 `std::list` is bigger than a C++98 `std::list`.

Comment: And it should always have been done that way! (just my $0.02).

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, is there a standard library implementation I can look at and study from?

Comment: Technically it's required to determine size() in constant time. How it does that is unspecified. There is however no known way of doing that without storing it! I suggest there has never been a serious implementation that worked like that even before complexity was specified as constant in C++11. 
 It's all well and good to allow for different implementations. But if different platforms have significantly different computational complexity then code is for practical purposes non-portable at scale.

Comment: @Zoomin [here is the implementation of `std::list::size()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_list.h#L479) in libstdc++.   It's implemented as the internal function `_M_get_size()`.  You can see that it is simply returning a member variable and not performing any logic.

Comment: @ZoomIn Both [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/tree/master/include) and [stdlibc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3) are open source versions of the standard library that you can look at